# Why CSS button selector [disabled] and &:disabled both works the same way?

Tags: css, sass

Please see this minimum example, I'm using SCSS here

```html
<button class="colon" disabled>&:disabled</button>
<button class="bracket" disabled>&[disabled]</button>
```

```
.colon {
  &:disabled {
    color: red;
  }
}

.bracket {
  &[disabled] {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Why `&[disabled]` also work?

Comment: because of the keyword `disabled` inside the tag and `&[disabled]` is just a text for the button so why it shouldn't display like that?

Comment: @Manjuboyz the shorthand `disabled='true'` trick me.

Comment: `disabled` by default will be`true` always, you can either change it in the `html` or you can modify it is `css` or jquery`, I just shared that as answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The :disabled selector matches every disabled element (mostly used on form elements).

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp

While [*] matches any attribute on the element. You can for example target classes like this:

```
div[class='myClassName'] {
  color: blue
}
```

Here is another example of how you can use the attribute-selector:

```css
button:disabled {
  color: red;
}

button[disabled='true'] {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<button disabled="true">my button</button>
<button disabled="false">my button</button>
```

(OBS! this will only style the buttons. Their functionality will still be disabled)